# This is about the euler 11th python

Tags: python

```
nums = [8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 00, 40, 00, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8,
        49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 4, 56, 62, 00,
        81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 3, 49, 13, 36, 65,
        52, 70, 95, 23, 4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 1, 32, 56, 71, 37, 2, 36, 91,
        22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80,
        24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3, 45, 2, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50,
        32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70,
        67, 26, 20, 68, 2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8, 40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21,
        24, 55, 58, 5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72,
        21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 00, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 00, 61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95,
        78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 3, 80, 4, 62, 16, 14, 9, 53, 56, 92,
        16, 39, 5, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 00, 17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57,
        86, 56, 00, 48, 35, 71, 89, 7, 5, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58,
        19, 80, 81, 68, 5, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 4, 89, 55, 40,
        4, 52, 8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 7, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66,
        88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 3, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69,
        4, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8, 46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36,
        20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 4, 36, 16,
        20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 1, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 5, 54,
        1, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 1, 89, 19, 67, 48]


def row(n):   #finds the row of the numbers
    number_row = n//20
    return number_row


def hor_mult(n):
    hor_final = 1
    num = 1
    for i in range(4):
        if n < 17+20*row(n):  #finds if the number is 4 digit away from the end of the row
            num *= nums[n+i]
            if num > hor_final:  #if the number is higher than final prints number
                print(num)
                hor_final = num
            else:
                hor_final = hor_final  #else the final num stays the same
        else:
            return hor_final    #




for n in range(400):
    print(hor_mult(n))
```

I am trying to find the biggest back to back multiplication of 4 number, but my code prints every 4 multiplication of back to back numbers.

First part of the code (def row)finds the row of the 4 numbers because all four numbers must be on the same row.

In the second part (hor_mult) I tried to find the biggest 4 back to back mult of nums

Comment: thats a 1d array ... there are no rows ....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are these issues:

- `if n < 17+20*row(n):` is a condition that does not depend on the loop, so it should not appear inside the loop. It is also a quite complex way to say that the column index should be less than 17, so why not write a function `col` instead of `row`? You can use the `%` operator for that.
- The check `if num > hor_final` should not be made while the product of four isn't completed yet, as there might still be a 0 to be included, making the product *less* than what it currently is. So this check should not be in the loop, but appear after it. Moreover, you want to compare products of *mulitple* calls of `hor_mult`, so this check shouldn't be inside that function, nor should `hor_final` be a local name inside that function. The result is only final when the loop in the main code (over 400) has finished, so `hor_final` should be defined *there*.
- `print(num)`: the function shouldn't print anything: it cannot know by itself whether the maximum was achieved as that depends on other calls of `hor_mult`. Printing is not a job for this function. This function's job should be just to return a product of four. It is for the caller to decide whether it is great enough and to print. That printing can only happen when **all** products have been calculated -- not before.
- `else: return hor_final`: no, you shouldn't return a partial product, not even 1. As indicated earlier, the corresponding `if` condition should be outside the loop, and its `else` case should return 0 (the least possible product when input is non-negative), not `hor_final`.
- In the main program loop, there are 400 calls of `print`. It should be clear that this is wrong. You want to execute `print` only once. The loop should serve to find out which returned value is the greatest. That's the purpose of the loop. After the loop you should print, and only then.

Here is how the code could be fixed:

```
def col(n):
    return n % 20

def hor_mult(n):
    if col(n) < 17:  # Only bother looping when there is room for 4 values
        num = 1
        for value in nums[n: n+4]:  # pythonic way to get those 4 values
            num *= value
        return num
    else:
        return 0  # When not enough values to make the product of 4.

# pythonic way to make those 400 calls and get the maximum 
hor_final = max(map(hor_mult, range(400)))  
print(hor_final)  # only print when you have full information
```

Note that the Euler Project challenge asks more than just this. You also need to check the products in other directions, which will be more challenging. To be really honest with you, seeing the problems in your attempt, I think Euler Project challenges are going to get too difficult at this stage, and I would advise you to first practice on simpler challenges.